# T-SQL Compare previous non-NULL and current row to filter out by difference value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, comparison, common-table-expression

My sample database (in fact a CTE statement data) looks like this:

```
eventdate   val
2012-03-23  3965
2012-03-26  3979
2012-03-27  3974
2012-03-28  3965
2012-03-29  3967
2012-03-30  3959
2012-04-02  3951
2012-04-03  3961
2012-04-04  3944
2012-04-05  3935
2012-04-09  3901
2012-04-10  3822
```

I want to remove the values that are less than 12 in difference.
This is my query and output:

```
SELECT
eventdate,
CASE
WHEN ABS(val - LAG(val) OVER (ORDER BY eventdate)) <= 12
THEN NULL
ELSE val
END AS val
FROM tbl_1
ORDER BY eventdate
```

The problem is that it compares between current and previous row.
This is what I get:

```
eventdate   val
2012-03-23  3965
2012-03-26  3979
2012-03-27  NULL
2012-03-28  NULL
2012-03-29  NULL
2012-03-30  NULL
2012-04-02  NULL
2012-04-03  NULL
2012-04-04  3944
2012-04-05  NULL
2012-04-09  3901
2012-04-10  3822
```

I need to compare between current and previous non-NULL value, I mean the last value that was not NULLed on the previous step.

This is what I need:

```
eventdate   val
2012-03-23  3965
2012-03-26  3979
2012-03-27  NULL
2012-03-28  3965
2012-03-29  NULL
2012-03-30  NULL
2012-04-02  3951
2012-04-03  NULL
2012-04-04  NULL
2012-04-05  3935
2012-04-09  3901
2012-04-10  3822
```

I tried the following. I made a self-referenced CTE query as above replacing `THEN NULL` with `THEN LAG(val) OVER (ORDER BY eventdate)` to copy last appropriate value and compare with next. Then remove duplicates. But it deadly loops on `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` with no output at all.

Seems this could be done by `CURSOR` only. I need the result set as CTE statement (`CURSOR` operations within the CTE), to use it in next query.

As far as I looked for `CURSOR` examples they all are done as a final `SELECT` to CTE. This is not an option for me!

I am running SQL Server 2014.

Many thanks for your help or thoughts!

Comment: You could look into doing something with a self-join or recursive cte, but this might be one of those rare cases where a cursor is the way to go.

Comment: I am with Tab.  For all the times you should not use a  cursor this may be a time to use a cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job:

```
declare @tbl_1 table (eventdate date, val int)
insert into @tbl_1(eventdate,val) values
('20120323',3965),
('20120326',3979),
('20120327',3974),
('20120328',3965),
('20120329',3967),
('20120330',3959),
('20120402',3951),
('20120403',3961),
('20120404',3944),
('20120405',3935),
('20120409',3901),
('20120410',3822)

;With Ord as (
    select eventdate,val,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY eventdate) as rn
    from @tbl_1
), Runs as (
    select eventdate,val,val as prevval,rn
    from Ord
    where rn = 1
    union all
    select
        o.eventdate,
        CASE WHEN ABS(o.val - r.prevval) <= 12 THEN NULL ELSE o.val END,
        CASE WHEN ABS(o.val - r.prevval) <= 12 THEN r.prevval ELSE o.val END,
        o.rn
    from
        Runs r
            inner join
        Ord o
            on
                r.rn = o.rn - 1
)
SELECT
    r.eventdate,r.val
from Runs r
```

Hopefully you can see what we're doing with the two new CTEs - the first (`Ord`) is just setting things up nicely so that we can easily perform a self join in `Runs` between the "current" row and the previous one - you may be able to incorporate its logic into the current CTE that's giving us this result set to work from.

In `Runs`, we also add a new column (`prevval`) that "remembers" the last non-NULL value that was used. It generates the result set you've asked for:

```
eventdate  val
---------- -----------
2012-03-23 3965
2012-03-26 3979
2012-03-27 NULL
2012-03-28 3965
2012-03-29 NULL
2012-03-30 NULL
2012-04-02 3951
2012-04-03 NULL
2012-04-04 NULL
2012-04-05 3935
2012-04-09 3901
2012-04-10 3822
```

And if it's still not clear what it's done, replace the final select with a `SELECT *`:

```
eventdate  val         prevval     rn
---------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
2012-03-23 3965        3965        1
2012-03-26 3979        3979        2
2012-03-27 NULL        3979        3
2012-03-28 3965        3965        4
2012-03-29 NULL        3965        5
2012-03-30 NULL        3965        6
2012-04-02 3951        3951        7
2012-04-03 NULL        3951        8
2012-04-04 NULL        3951        9
2012-04-05 3935        3935        10
2012-04-09 3901        3901        11
2012-04-10 3822        3822        12
```